# How to get seed co-ordinates from surface area of polygons in Voronoi?

Tags: python, math, voronoi

I know the surface area of all the polygons in my Voronoi plot and would like to get the seed co-ordinates. Is this possible in Python (or any other tool)?

Comment: What do you mean by "area"? Do you only know the surface area of each area or do you have more information like a polygon? If you only know the surface area then there usually would be many possible patterns of areas that could have these same surface areas.

Comment: I only know the surface area of each region - how much space each polygon should occupy in the voronoi. So yes, there would be many possible patterns.

Comment: If the question which exact Voronoi pattern is used truly does not matter and we are talking about a 2D diagram: You can just have the points in a perfect vertical line in the exact center of the plot. Take the percentage of each area on the sum of all areas. Take the height (or width) of the diagram. Multiply the height (or width) with each percentage. This gives you the heights (or widths) of the vertically (or horizontally) stacked areas. Now just start from one side. First center is `(width/2, first_height/2)`. Second center is `(width/2,first_height+second_height/2)` etc...

Comment: Similar simple solutions are possible with all basic shapes that can be directly proportionally applied to a single axis. E.g. horizontally stacked rectangles or diagonally stacked stripes where the edges are triangles. Finding natural-looking patterns is probably a lot more complicated because there are so many moving parts at once when you move towards an optimization. That's more similar to a puzzle-solving algorithm which usually is pretty comlicated and computionally really expensive.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @ewz93 Thanks a lot for the suggestions! I see that there are ways to do this for simple shapes but not for polygons. So, I would be able to build Treemaps but not Voronoi diagrams.